# find all the possible path between a start node and end node in neo4j using cypher query language

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have multiple nodes and many different relationship between 2 nodes ie the start node and end node. I want to find all the possible path between a start node and end node in neo4j using cypher query language

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the [MATCH documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#query-match) helpful here, especially [variable-length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels).

An example:

```
MATCH path = (start:Label1{id:12345})-[*]-(end:Label2{id:67890})
RETURN path
```

Be aware that highly connected graphs may have trouble if you do not add an upper limit to the size of the paths.